# Angular 2 one way binding removing selected option of select tag

Tags: html, angular

I have this code in my test.component.html file:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Supplier</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

It shows up nice like this:

[image]

For some reason, when I add one-way binding from the template to the Component on that select tag the selected option disappears:

```
<select (ngModel)="item.supplier" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Supplier</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

[image]

What is causing this to happen and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's disappearing because you're binding to the `output` event for `ngModelChange` but not actually using the value provided by the `$event`.

This should work for you (note I assume there's an item object already initialised in the component).

```
  <select [ngModel]="''" (ngModelChange)="item.supplier = $event" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Supplier</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
```

This is using `ngModel` in the input and output bindings separately, rather than the two-way binding `[(ngModel)]` - see [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngModel).

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what this part does? [ngModel]="''"

Comment: No worries mate. That part is binding the empty string value as the initial value of the select element, binding via the `ngModel` input property. So the initial selected value will be the first option tag (the one with 'Supplier' as the text.
As an aside, I haven't typically used these input/output events separately, rather have used the two-way binding i.e. [(ngModel)]="item.supplier", but this expanded form can be handy in some cases (as noted in the Angular doc example linked in the answer).